# JQuery Sorting array of object using date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have an array of objects which includes **lastModifiedDate** property in each object.
I want to sort the array of objects according to **lastModifiedDate** property in ascending as well as descending order. If the dates are same then the sorting should be based on time of the date.

```
var completeData = [{name: 'xyz', lastModifiedDate: 1579329711458}, {name: 'abc', lastModifiedDate: 1579339014519}]
```

I have tried the below code to sort the above array.

For Ascending order:

```
completeData.sort(function(a, b){
   return new Date( a.lastModifiedDate ) < new Date( b.lastModifiedDate );
});
```

For Descending order:

```
completeData.sort(function(a, b){
    return new Date( a.lastModifiedDate ) > new Date( b.lastModifiedDate );
});
```

Comment: Both your code samples for ascending and descending sorting look the same.

Comment: I missed to change greater and less symbol

Comment: There's no need to transform `lastModifiedDate` into a `Date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `lastModifiedDate` is numberic value of timestamp then why need to compare date object of those timestamps you can compare those numbers only for efficient execution of sort as below.

```
completeData.sort(function(a, b){
   return  a.lastModifiedDate - b.lastModifiedDate;
});
```

When you need to display date formate you can use Date object for presentation purpose.

Comment: @Tales please check jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/t3m2bcgL/ it is working correctly.. if you want in descending order then you have to use `return  b.lastModifiedDate - a.lastModifiedDate;`

Comment: Thanks you. Its working

Answer (score 1):

For Descending ,

```
completeData.sort(function(a, b){
                var nameA= a.lastModifiedDate, nameB=b.lastModifiedDate
                if (nameA < nameB) 
                    return 1 
                if (nameA > nameB)
                    return -1
                return 0 //default return value (no sorting)
            });
```

For ascending ,

```
completeData.sort(function(a, b){
                    var nameA= a.lastModifiedDate, nameB=b.lastModifiedDate
                    if (nameA < nameB) 
                        return -1 
                    if (nameA > nameB)
                        return 1
                    return 0 //default return value (no sorting)
                });
```

This is for Date.

Comment: The code is working. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer . ? @Tales

Comment: I have accepted the above code as it was shorter

Answer (score 1):

```
var completeData = [
  {
     name: 'xyz', 
     lastModifiedDate: 1579329711458
  },
  {
     name: 'abc', 
     lastModifiedDate: 1579339014519
  }
];
var result = completeData.sort(function (a, b) {
   return b.lastModifiedDate - a.lastModifiedDate;
})

console.log(result);
```